# How to strip a word from a Python list when it's attached to another word?

Tags: python

I'm trying to remove html tag from a string, so i tried the following:

```
def cleaner(raw):
    stopwords = ['<ul>', '</ul>', '<li>', '</li>']
    querywords = raw.split()

    resultwords  = [word for word in querywords if word.lower() not in stopwords]
    result = ' '.join(resultwords)

    return result
```

The problem with this code is that it fails to remove the following word where a tag is attached to a word: `.. <li>Drive ..`. Is there any way to remove such cases as well?

Comment: Can you give an example of `querywords`? There are probably solutions with either a regular expression or with `str.replace()`.

Comment: Have you considered html parsers? A simple tool for that is [beautifulsoup](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/) It would do the job with a couple of lines of code and save you the headache that comes with searches for tags in strings (with or without regex).

Comment: Or `xml.etree.ElementTree` which is standard available so you don't need to install additional packages.

Comment: I would second @0buz 's comment - using regex to handle HTML is a no-no unless you want a lot of headaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple example. Note this requires [`pip install beautifulsoup4`](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

my_html="""<div> This is my list:
<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>
</div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(my_html, 'html.parser')
print(soup.text)
```

*Output:*

```
This is my list:
Coffee
Tea
Milk
```

Answer (score 1):

This removes all tags:

```
import re

query='<HTML><ul>list</ul>more text<li>list item</li>more html text</html>'

def cleaner(raw):
    stopwords = ['<ul>', '</ul>', '<li>', '</li>']
    result = raw
    result = re.sub(r'<.*?>', '', raw)  # or use ' ' if you need spaces
    return result                       # OR:
    return re.sub(r' +', ' ', result)   # remove multiple spaces when needed
    
print(cleaner(query))
> listmore textlist itemmore html text
```

This removes only the tags in your list:

```
query='<HTML><ul>asfa</ul>lsfj;aj;lf<li>ahsdfl</li>'

def cleaner(raw):
    stopwords = ['<ul>', '</ul>', '<li>', '</li>']
    result = raw
    for stopword in stopwords:
        result = result.replace(stopword, '')
    return result
    
print(cleaner(query))
> <HTML>listmore textlist itemmore html text</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
resultwords = [word.replace(a,'') for a in stopwords for word in querywords]
```

---

Altogether:

```
def cleaner(raw):
    stopwords = ['<ul>', '</ul>', '<li>', '</li>']
    querywords = raw.split()
    resultwords = [word.replace(a,'') for a in stopwords for word in querywords]
    result = ' '.join(resultwords)
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
import re

def cleaner(raw):
    stopwords = ['<ul>', '</ul>', '<li>', '</li>']
    replace_ = re.compile("|".join(stopwords))
    
    return " ".join([replace_.sub("", word) for word in raw.split()])

print(cleaner("<ul>test</ul> <li>Drive<li>")) # test Drive
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for removing every html tag using `re`

```
def cleaner(raw):
    raw = re.sub(r"<.*?>", " ",  raw)       
    return raw.strip()

raw = "<li>Test</li><ul>Drive</ul><h3>Title</h3><body>body of the text</body>"
```

**output:**

'Test  Drive  Title  body of the text'

Answer (score 0):

If your issue is while your querywords are prefix with html tags then, I think you can iterate the querywords and check each word is not starting with with any one of the stopword.

```
temp=[]
for each_word in querywords:
    for each_stop in stopwords:
        if not each_word.startswith(each_stop):
            temp.append(each_word)
```

This may not be efficient. We can replace with list comprehension.

-Siva

Answer (score 0):

This may help :).

```
def cleaner(raw):
    stopwords = ['<ul>', '</ul>', '<li>', '</li>']
    result = ""
    for word in raw.split():
        for tag in stopwords:
            if tag in word:
                word = word.replace(tag, "")
        
        if(word != ""):
            result += word +" "

    return result.rstrip()
```